# Can't reach Locust WebInterface "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: python, windows, locust

I wanted to test my project with Locust on Windows 10.

The script seems to run properly (no errors in CMD), but i can't connect to the web interface http://127.0.0.1:8089 (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

I am guessing, that this has to do with browser/Windows config, but i can't find the problem. I have no proxy set up in LAN settings, i get my IP from DNS, and i have no changes in my hosts file.

locustfile.py:

```
python
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        self.logout()

    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/login", {"username":"tester", "password":"abcd1234"})

    def logout(self):
        self.client.post("/logout", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"})

    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        self.client.get("/profile")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
    host="http://google.com"
```

CMD:

```
D:\workspace\WebTesting>locust
```

CMD result:

```
[2019-05-13 09:49:45,069] LB6-001-DTMH/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089
[2019-05-13 09:49:45,070] LB6-001-DTMH/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 0.11.0
```

When i interrupt the script in the command line i get the `KeyboardInterrupt` message and some statistics without data.

`python -m http.server 8089` seems to work.

Answer (score 14):

Try going to http://localhost:8089/

I am not quite sure why, but I can't reach the Locust webinterface through http://127.0.0.1 either (other webservers run fine locally with this address), but going to localhost does work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue. Instead of using IP address, try using localhost.
**http://localhost:portnumber** -> **http://localhost:8089**. This solved the issue for me.